# Problemas con formato de elementos fuera del navbar en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy usando Bootstrap 4.0. Quiero poner en la barra de navegación algunos elementos que no están dentro del menú al lado derecho del navbar.
Pero el texto se muestra en un formato diferente del que tiene el texto dentro del navbar.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Dropdown
             </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="text-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Elemento1</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Elemento2</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Elemento3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

En los modelos de Bootstrap no hay algo similar. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
*Elemento1*, *Elemento2* y *Elemento3* quiero que tengan el mismo formato que el menú.

Comment: No veo exactamente a qué estilo te refieres, ¿podrías indicarnos cuál es el resultado esperado o deseado?

Comment: En el div del final hay tres elementos que al mostrarse se ven con las letras en otro formato.

Comment: Tienen el mismo formato que la palabra "Navbar"

Comment: quieres decir que esos tres elementos tienen una fuente distinta a la de los elementos de la barra de navegación de bootstrap?

Comment: En la pregunta dices que quieres poner elementos dentro del menú al lado derecho. Lo que no queda claro es **qué elementos quieres poner**, porque en tu código, en la barra de navegación, hay tres elementos con la clase `.navbar-brand`, que claramente no quieres. ¿Deseas poner al lado derecho una barra de navegación parecida a la que está en el lado izquierdo? ¿O deseas poner otro tipo de elementos?

Comment: *Elemento1*, *Elemento2* y *Elemento3* no se ven igual que *Home*, *Link*, *Dropdown*, *Disabled*. Se ven diferentes. Quiero que en apariencia se vean igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Dropdown
             </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
   

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
<li clas"nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Elemento 1 </a>
    </li>
<li clas"nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Elemento 2 </a>
        </li>
<li clas"nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Elemento 3 </a>
        </li>
</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Lo solucionas quitando el `div` de los elementos que quieres a la derecha y los pones identicos como los otros en sus respectivos `ul` y `li` pero en tu etiqueta `ul` añades la clase `pull-xs-right`, y tendrias que ir cambiando el `xs` dependiendo la vista que necesites.

Porque segun la documentacion de bootstrap, como lo estabas intentando sirve pero solo para texto